# 各レコードに対する過去直近７日間のデータ集計

Tags: sqlite

SQLで各レコードの過去直近７日間のデータを集計したいです。
使用DBはSQLite3です。
具体例だと

日付　　　　|  歩数　
     -----------------------
2018-01-01　| 6000
2018-01-02　| 5500
2018-01-03　| 200
2018-01-04　| 9700
2018-01-05　| 1100
2018-01-06　| 5000
2018-01-07　| 800
2018-01-08　| 3600
2018-01-09　| 6000
2018-01-10　| 0

というデータに対して

日付　　　　|  過去１週間の平均歩数　
     -----------------------

2018-01-08　| 3187
2018-01-09　| 3700
2018-01-10　| 3771

のように集計がしたいです。（2018-01-01から2018-01-07の集計はできてもできなくてもよいです。）

この集計を１つのSQLで書けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

相関サブクエリを使えばわかりやすいでしょうか

```
SELECT
  日付,
  (SELECT AVG(t2.歩数)
   FROM t AS t2
   WHERE date(t1.日付, '-7 days') <= t2.日付 AND t2.日付 < t1.日付) AS 過去１週間の平均歩数
FROM t AS t1;
```

行数が多くパフォーマンスが問題になる場合は自己結合しつつ集計することでしょうか

```
SELECT t1.日付, AVG(t2.歩数) AS 過去１週間の平均歩数
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN t AS t2
ON date(t1.日付, '-7 days') <= t2.日付 AND t2.日付 < t1.日付
GROUP BY t1.日付;
```